# Is DNS lookup time affected by the use of subdomains and CNAME?

Tags: dns, nameservers

Is DNS lookup time slowed down by the use of subdomains and CNAME? As I understand it, if a client wants to lookup for example `rweb.stat.ucla.edu` at least four steps are needed:

```
[registrar] NS ucla.edu ==> ns2.dns.ucla.edu
[ns2.dns.ucla.edu] NS stat.ucla.edu ==> dns.stat.ucla.edu
[dns.stat.ucla.edu] CNAME rweb.stat.ucla.edu ==> id-86-243.stat.ucla.edu
[dns.stat.ucla.edu] A id-86-243.stat.ucla.edu  ==> 128.97.86.243
```

Does this mean the client has to connect to each of these servers when visiting the page? Or do the DNS servers connect to each other and directly resolve (and cache) `rweb.stat.ucla.edu ==> 128.97.86.243`? Also it is not clear to me how much work is involved in finding the initial record for the root domain?

Comment: Most DNS servers are configured to cache.  Like a name change can take 12 hours to migrate across the country.

Comment: What exactly do they cache? The entire roundtrip? Or individual lookups?

Comment: In general they cache what they have cached.  It is typically just a queue wher the last x are cached with a timeout.  There is not a hard rule about how a DNS server must determine the answer.  This is not really my expertise.  Why do you care?   It is not the client that navigates to the multiple servers.  It is the responsibility of you DNS server to go out and get what it does not have.

Comment: Great book is Computer Networks and Internets by Comer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the registrar is *never* involved in the actual DNS lookup. Registrars (and indeed, registries) are administrative entities outside the scope of the DNS protocol. The actual lookup process looks more like this:

1. Ask root servers for `A` of `rweb.stat.ucla.edu.`.

   - They won't tell you, but they'll point you to servers for `edu.`.
2. Ask the `edu.` servers for `A` of `rweb.stat.ucla.edu.`.

   - They won't tell you, but they'll point you to servers for `ucla.edu.`
3. Ask the `ucla.edu` servers for `A` of `rweb.stat.ucla.edu.`.

   - `stat.ucla.edu` could be a zone that is delegated to yet another set of nameservers, in which case you'll get a referral answer for the third time.
   - But let't say it's not.
   - You get an answer: `rweb.stat.ucla.edu.` has `CNAME` `id-86-243.stat.ucla.edu`.

Now you have to start all over again and look up `id-86-243.stat.ucla.edu`...

...except that because the target of the `CNAME` is inside the same zone as the original record (or, in general, inside any zone that happens to be served from the same nameserver), the nameserver will helpfully give you the `A` record for `id-86-243.stat.ucla.edu` in the additional section of the DNS response. The resolver will notice this and won't have to run after the `A` record itself.

Because resolvers cache answers, many queries can be answered from the cache and don't actually have to be asked every time. Especially the first few steps of the query are all likely to be already cached by the resolver, except immediately after it starts up with a cold cache. So the resolver can probably usually start at step 3 (because it remembers what the nameservers for `ucla.edu.` are from its cache) or at least at step 2 (because it remembers what the nameservers for `edu.` are) if it doesn't already know the final answer.

So the short answer to your question is **yes**, using `CNAME` makes more work for the resolver and makes the resolution process take longer. But in practice it doesn't matter very much because the resolver's cache is so helpful. And if the `CNAME`'s target is in the same zone as the `CNAME` record itself, it matters even less because of the helpful additional record.

Comment: Do you know, how can I find out if a subdomain is using CNAME or A record? Essentially, I have several requests to subdomains. Basically, `a.domain` and `b.domain` and the `DNS` lookup for both takes about the same. I suppose this means the `dns` resolution is not cached.